# Had to re-write a DB Query for Rails 6 due to Squeel gem: Error: undefined method `call' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

I recently had to re-write an APP called CtrlPanel which I have all done and working well. (Thanks to several users on StackOverflow for helping with that!)

I am now onto the second app I have to rewrite called Emissions Gateway.  Just like CtrlPanel this WebApp had a gem in it called squeel which uses its own Monkey Patched DSL language for the DB queries so I have to re-write ALL of them in normal Ruby on Rails/ActiveRecord queries.

This APP has a LOT more of these queries and they are more complicated instead just just a few fields mapping to other fields they are using model names and symbol name combinations. I need to re-write all of them and I am having an issue on the very first one.

The error isn't what I was expecting?  It is not giving me an error with the query itself it is giving me an error on what is calling the query if I understand it right?  This is the error message:

undefined method `call' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

According to Better Errors it is the projects_controller.rb that is making the call:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def dashboard
    @projects = current_user.authorized_projects.order("created_at desc")
  end
```

What I wanted to make sure of before I start going down a troubleshooting rabbit hole is I wanted to know if my query re-write does look ok, even though it isn't giving me a syntax error I'm sure there can be other things wrong with it and I am still relatively new to this.

Here is the originally query using that darn squeel language:

```
#Project.joins{vendor}.where{(projects.vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id }) |
   (vendors.parent_vendor_id.eq my{ vendor_id })}.uniq
```

Here is my re-written query:

```
Project.joins(vendor).where({projects.(:vendor_id) => my.(:vendor_id)}) 
        OR
        ({vendors.(:parent_vendor_id) => my(:vendor_id)}).uniq
```

I thought I would TRY to keep it really simple and only supply the bare minimum.
Based on above do I have the syntax of the query correct or am I getting this wrong?  I didn't have to re-write any queries on ctrlpanel that used classname.symbole like the queries are in this app.  If it helps to know this APP was a much older APP, written in Ruby 2.0 and Rails 3.2. It was a ROYAL PAIN to get it to boot and to get the login prompt to finally come up, I get this error right after it accepts my login.

If I need to post the entire user model, the projects model & controller and the vendor model to be able to answer the question on if my query is right or to reveal more info on this error let me know and I will add them. Was trying to keep it in more simple terms to make it easier if possible, but if that can't be done I will happily supply the rest.

Thanks In advance to anyone who can help.

Scott

Comment: Not familiar with squeel but I believe the equivalent would be `Project.joins(:vendor).where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id}).or(Project.joins(:vendor).where(vendors: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id}))` alternatively `Project.joins(:vendor).where(Project.arel_table[:vendor_id].eq(vendor_id).or(Vendor.arel_table[:parent_vendor_id].eq(vendor_id)))`. Mostly I am unsure what the `my` block does. If it just refers to a local variable then either of the suggestions should be equivalent.

Comment: The error that you mentioned most probably occurs at `projects.(:vendor_id)`  - this is a valid Ruby code but it does something quite different from what you expect. What you actually do here is an attempt to send a `call` message to `projects` with the `:vendor_id` as the parameter: `projects.(:vendor_id) == projects.call(:vendor_id)`.

Comment: @engineersmnky `my {}` seems to be how you access the "outer" context due to the level of metaprogramming hackery involved.  So `my { vendor_id }` calls the method on the controller. AR doesn't have the same scoping issues so there is no equivilent. https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#the-squeel-query-dsl

Comment: @engineersmnky I am more than willing to let you answer the questions in the future if you would prefer?  I don't want to take any credit as your help has been invaluable.

Comment: Thank You @max, this is very helpful!  I was trying to find the documentation to explain how squeel worked.  I don't know WHY someone would ever use a gem like that for the very issue I am running into.  Gem stops working, all the queries are now useless.  Seems like you are integrating a future problem.

Comment: @ScottMilella I don't mind the rep points don't really mean anything. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @engineersmnky

This query worked:

```
Project.joins(:vendor)
       .where(projects: {vendor_id: vendor_id})
       .or(
         Project.joins(:vendor)
                .where(vendors: {parent_vendor_id: vendor_id})
        )
```

Sorry for the delayed response.

I GREATLY appreciate the help.

Scott